# Clip a shapefile by a line border

Tags: sql, google-big-query

I'm trying to generate a clipped file of a sample polygon geography (in this case, zip) and the U.S. coastline.

This is the query I currently have:

```
select
state_code, 
zip_code,
st_union(st_dump(st_intersection(zip_code_geom,coastline_geom),2)) as geometry
from bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes zip
cross join bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.coastline coastline
where st_intersects(zip_code_geom, coastline_geom)
```

This query works perfectly with two polygon shapefiles, but for whatever reason won't work with a polygon (zip) and linestring (coastline) shapefile intersection. All I'm trying to do here is to clip the geography by the coastline for the shapefile to display correctly.

NOTE: I believe the zip file is already clipped by coastline, but I'm trying to write this code out for shapefiles that have not already been clipped.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: you can't clip by a line as it has no inside/outside to determine which parts to keep

Answer (score 1):

An intersection is shape consisting of points that belongs to both shapes. So assuming coastline_geom is really a line, an intersection of polygon with coastline_geom is part of that coastline_geom (line) intersecting the polygon. I.e. you are clipping coastline rather than your polygon.

I would try to turn coastline into an area surrounded by the coastline as border.
See `ST_MakePolygon` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_makepolygon and clip by this polygon

Then clip your polygon with this area. Something like

```sql
select
state_code, 
zip_code,
st_intersection(zip_code_geom, ST_MakePolygon(coastline_geom)) as geometry
from bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes zip
cross join bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.coastline coastline
where st_intersects(zip_code_geom, ST_MakePolygon(coastline_geom))
```